# python selenium xpath horror

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

i know i am doing something wrong here  but i would like your help on this one

i have this html code

```
<span id='some text'>some text</span>  
<ul> this is what I would like to grab </ul>
<span id='some more text'>some more text</span>
```

so i tried something and since this is the first time i am working with xpath i was quite sure i was doing wrong.

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//ul[preceding:://span[@id="some text"] and  following:://span[@id="some more text"] ')
```

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `id` attribute is supposed to be unique, so one is enough to select a branch.

To get the `<ul>` tag following the `<span id='some text'>`:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@id='some text']/following-sibling::ul[1]")
```

, and with a CSS selector:

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("span[id='some text'] + ul")
```

Comment: wow thanks that totally worked. i wasn't expecting an answer this quick